# Will compizconfig settings manager be included in Natty?

Tags: 11.04, compiz

Since unity has to be configured from within Compizconfig Settings Manager, will it be included in Natty?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No, ccsm will never be installed by default. It is quite possibly the worst UI ever invented. It is completely autogenerated so every setting of a certain type is treated identically even if they make no sense to be shown that way. Settings depend on each other in ways the UI can't handle for you and putting the wrong values in for some of the settings will leave you with a desktop that does not work.

It is strictly a poweruser "break my toys" tool and always will be. That said, hopefully the Unity folks cook something up for adjusting the settings they deem worthy of adjustment. I could see a nice little UI for adjusting number of workspaces, launcher autohide, and maybe a couple more somewhat common options.

Answer (score 2):

There hasn't been any suggestion from Canonical or the Unity team about this. Personally I very much doubt it will be included by default.

I imagine the Unity team will make sure they choose great defaults that ensure most users won't ever need to delve into the CompizConfig Settings Manager (personally I think the name's quite snazzy...)

Comment: Why wouldn't they include it though? If we are allowed to change our theme etc, why shouldn't new users be presented with the option to change other settings as well? Are we GNOME? Are we apple? Are we windows?

Comment: Because it's a pretty big beast of a configuration tool to present to new users. Perhaps a tab could be added to the Appearance dialogue? I expect they'd welcome patches...